# Is there any way to get the first date of the month without using moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, reduce

```
const startOfMonth = moment().startOf("month").format("x");
```

The output above is 1661961600000
My goal is to get the first date of the month without using moment

Comment: `const date = new Date(); date.setDate(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Date constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date), setting the year and month to the same as the given date, but with a date argument of one:

```js
function getStartOfMonth(date) {
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1)
}

console.log('Start of current month:', getStartOfMonth(new Date()).toString());
console.log('Start of current month (ms):', getStartOfMonth(new Date()).getTime());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```